# Generating a template pack

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic

`Generate<P<3>, P<5,0>, P<4,0,0>, P<3,0,1>>::type` is to be

```
Pack< A<0>, A<0,0>, A<0,0,0>, A<0,0,1>, A<0,0,2>, A<0,0,3>, A<0,1>, A<0,1,0>, A<0,1,1>, A<0,1,2>, A<0,2>, A<0,3>, A<0,4>, A<1>, A<2> >
```

because `P<3>` means that `P<n>` exists for n = 0,1,2;  `P<5,0>` means that `A<0,n>` exists for n = 0,1,2,3,4;  `P<4,0,0>` means that `A<0,0,n>` exists for n = 0,1,2,3;  and `P<3,0,1>` means that `A<0,1,n>` exists for n = 0,1,2.
In terms of ordering, `A<n1,n2,n3,...,nk,x,...>` will always precede `A<n1,n2,n3,...,nk,y,...>` if x < y and `A<n1,n2,n3,...,nk>` will always precede `A<n1,n2,n3,...,nk, ...>`, where the second elipses ... is non-empty.
So I need to write out the implementation of `Generate<Packs...>`.

Motivation for this:  If `template <int... Is> class Object` has certain possibilities for its `Is...` pack, defined by constants like the 3, 5, 4, and 3 above, then a pack of all of its possible types will allow
generation of specific `Object<Is...>` instances by iterating through the pack.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <int...> class A;
template <typename...> struct Pack;
template <int...> struct P;

template <int N, int Count, typename Front, typename Output> struct GenerateHelper;

template <int N, int Count, int... Is, typename... As>
struct GenerateHelper<N, Count, P<Is...>, Pack<As...>> :
    GenerateHelper<N, Count + 1, P<Is...>, Pack<As..., A<Is..., Count>>> {};

template <int N, int... Is, typename... As>
struct GenerateHelper<N, N, P<Is...>, Pack<As...>> {
    using type = Pack<As...>;
};

template <typename...> struct Generate;

// Simple special case just to start off.  Generate has only one pack to deal with.
template <int N, int... Is>
struct Generate<P<N, Is...>> : GenerateHelper<N, 0, P<Is...>, Pack<>> {};

int main() {
    using T = Generate<P<3,0,0>>::type;
    std::cout << std::is_same<T, Pack<A<0,0,0>, A<0,0,1>, A<0,0,2>>>::value << '\n'; // true
}
```

But now I'm stuck with the case of just 2 packs in Generate.  Can anyone help me continue?

Idea:  For 2 packs, just generate separately, merge the two `Pack`s, and then sort after?  But then the sorting will be the hardest part I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is realizing that the sequence you get from each "generation" procedure is already sorted, and the problem reduces to merging several sorted lists.

For simplicity, I made `A`, `Pack` and `P` empty structs.

```
template <int...> class A {};
template <typename...> struct Pack {};
template <int...> struct P {};
```

Generate a pack of `A`s from one `P`:

```
template<int I, int... Tail>
auto do_sequence_for(P<I, Tail...>) -> std::make_integer_sequence<int, I>;

template<class PP>
using sequence_for = decltype(do_sequence_for(PP()));

template<int I, int... Front, int... Tail>
auto do_generate_single(P<I, Front...>, std::integer_sequence<int, Tail...>)
     -> Pack<A<Front..., Tail>...>;

template<class PP>
using generate_single = decltype(do_generate_single(PP(), sequence_for<PP>()));
```

Lexicographical comparison of two `A`s:

```
template<class A1, class A2>
struct compare; // returns A1 < A2

template<int I, int J, int...Is, int...Js>
struct compare<A<I, Is...>, A<J, Js...>> : std::integral_constant<bool, I < J> {};

template<int I, int...Is, int...Js>
struct compare<A<I, Is...>, A<I, Js...>> : compare<A<Is...>, A<Js...>> {};

template<int...Is>
struct compare<A<Is...>, A<>> : std::false_type {};

template<int J, int...Js>
struct compare<A<>, A<J, Js...>> : std::true_type {};
```

Merging two sorted packs of `A`s:

```
template<class Pack1, class Pack2, class Result=Pack<>>
struct merge2;

template<class A1, class...A1s, class A2, class...A2s, class...R>
struct merge2<Pack<A1, A1s...>, Pack<A2, A2s...>, Pack<R...>>
    : std::conditional_t<compare<A1, A2>::value,
                         merge2<Pack<A1s...>, Pack<A2, A2s...>, Pack<R..., A1>>,
                         merge2<Pack<A1, A1s...>, Pack<A2s...>, Pack<R..., A2>>>
{};

template<class...A1s, class...R>
struct merge2<Pack<A1s...>, Pack<>, Pack<R...>>
{
    using type = Pack<R..., A1s...>;
};

template<class A2, class...A2s, class...R>
struct merge2<Pack<>, Pack<A2, A2s...>, Pack<R...>>
{
    using type = Pack<R..., A2, A2s...>;
};
```

Merge many sorted packs of `A`s:

```
template<class... Packs>
struct merge;

template<class P1>
struct merge<P1> {
    using type = P1;
};

template<class P1, class P2, class... Ps>
struct merge<P1, P2, Ps...> : merge<typename merge2<P1, P2>::type, Ps...> {};
```

Bringing it all together:

```
template<class...Ps>
struct Generate{
    using type = typename merge<generate_single<Ps>...>::type;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28799024e82e1b97).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Visual Studio 2015 will not compile T.C.'s excellent solution (due to some bug it has), so the following is adapted by me that compiles on both Visual Studio 2015 and GCC 5.1.0 (and also generalizes to any integral type, any class, etc...).  Only his `generate_single` function needed to be replaced.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

// Another way to generate a pack of A's from one P than the above.
template <typename T, template<T...> class Class, T N, T Count, typename Front, typename Output> struct GenerateSingleHelper;

template <typename T, template<T...> class Class, T N, T Count, template <T...> class Z, T... Is, template <typename...> class PackOfPacks, typename... As>
struct GenerateSingleHelper<T, Class, N, Count, Z<Is...>, PackOfPacks<As...>> : GenerateSingleHelper<T, Class, N, Count + 1, Z<Is...>, PackOfPacks<As..., Class<Is..., Count>>> {};

template <typename T, template<T...> class Class, T N, template <T...> class Z, T... Is, template <typename...> class PackOfPacks, typename... As>
struct GenerateSingleHelper<T, Class, N, N, Z<Is...>, PackOfPacks<As...>> {
    using type = PackOfPacks<As...>;
};

template <typename T, template<T...> class Class, template <typename...> class PackOfPacks, typename> struct GenerateSingle;

template <typename T, template<T...> class Class, template <typename...> class PackOfPacks, template <T...> class Z, T N, T... Is>
struct GenerateSingle<T, Class, PackOfPacks, Z<N, Is...>> : GenerateSingleHelper<T, Class, N, 0, Z<Is...>, PackOfPacks<>> {};

// Lexicographical comparison of two A's.
template <typename T, typename A1, typename A2> struct Compare;  // Determines if A1 < A2.

template <typename T, template <T...> class Pack, T I, T J, T... Is, T... Js>
struct Compare<T, Pack<I, Is...>, Pack<J, Js...>> : std::integral_constant<bool, I < J> {};

template <typename T, template <T...> class Pack, T I, T... Is, T... Js>
struct Compare<T, Pack<I, Is...>, Pack<I, Js...>> : Compare<T, Pack<Is...>, Pack<Js...>> {};

template <typename T, template <T...> class Pack, T... Is>
struct Compare<T, Pack<Is...>, Pack<>> : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, template <T...> class Pack, T J, T... Js>
struct Compare<T, Pack<>, Pack<J, Js...>> : std::true_type {};  // J is needed to indicate that Pack<J, Js...> is not empty.

// Merging two sorted packs of A's.
template <typename T, template <typename...> class PackOfPacks, typename PackOfPacks1, typename PackOfPacks2, typename Result = PackOfPacks<>> struct MergeTwoPacks;

template <typename T, template <typename...> class PackOfPacks, typename A1, typename... A1s, typename A2, typename... A2s, typename... Accumulated>
struct MergeTwoPacks<T, PackOfPacks, PackOfPacks<A1, A1s...>, PackOfPacks<A2, A2s...>, PackOfPacks<Accumulated...>> : std::conditional_t<Compare<T, A1, A2>::value,
    MergeTwoPacks<T, PackOfPacks, PackOfPacks<A1s...>, PackOfPacks<A2, A2s...>, PackOfPacks<Accumulated..., A1>>,
    MergeTwoPacks<T, PackOfPacks, PackOfPacks<A1, A1s...>, PackOfPacks<A2s...>, PackOfPacks<Accumulated..., A2>>> {};

template <typename T, template <typename...> class PackOfPacks, typename... A1s, typename... Accumulated>
struct MergeTwoPacks<T, PackOfPacks, PackOfPacks<A1s...>, PackOfPacks<>, PackOfPacks<Accumulated...>> {
    using type = PackOfPacks<Accumulated..., A1s...>;  // Since PackOfPacks<A1s...> is already sorted.
};

template <typename T, template <typename...> class PackOfPacks, typename A2, typename... A2s, typename... Accumulated>
struct MergeTwoPacks<T, PackOfPacks, PackOfPacks<>, PackOfPacks<A2, A2s...>, PackOfPacks<Accumulated...>> {  // A2 is needed to indicate that PackOfPacks<A2, A2s...> is not empty.
    using type = PackOfPacks<Accumulated..., A2, A2s...>;  // Since PackOfPacks<A2s...> is already sorted.
};

// Merging any number of sorted packs of A's.
template <typename T, template <typename...> class PackOfPacks, typename... Packs> struct Merge;

template<typename T, template <typename...> class PackOfPacks, typename First, typename Second, typename... Rest>
struct Merge<T, PackOfPacks, First, Second, Rest...> : Merge<T, PackOfPacks, typename MergeTwoPacks<T, PackOfPacks, First, Second>::type, Rest...> {};

template <typename T, template <typename...> class PackOfPacks, typename Last>
struct Merge<T, PackOfPacks, Last> {
    using type = Last;
};

// Putting it all together.
template <typename T, template <T...> class Class, template <typename...> class PackOfPacks, typename... Packs>
struct Generate : Merge<T, PackOfPacks, typename GenerateSingle<T, Class, PackOfPacks, Packs>::type...> {};

// Testing.
template <int...> class A {};
template <typename...> struct PackOfPacks;
template <int...> struct P;

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same<
        Generate<int, A, PackOfPacks, P<3>, P<5,0>, P<4,0,0>, P<3,0,1>>::type,
        PackOfPacks< A<0>, A<0,0>, A<0,0,0>, A<0,0,1>, A<0,0,2>, A<0,0,3>, A<0,1>, A<0,1,0>, A<0,1,1>, A<0,1,2>, A<0,2>, A<0,3>, A<0,4>, A<1>, A<2> >
    >::value << '\n';  // true
}
```